# Can i install Xen Hypervisor on a dedicated server that is already in use

Tags: vps, xen, hypervisor

I have a dedicated server, currently i sell shared hosting on this server...
Now i want to sell VPS also on my server. Is there a way i can sell VPS?
Can i use Xen Hypervisor,will it disturb my shared hosting accounts and settings ?

Answer (score 4):

XenServer (ESXi, Hyper-V Server, etc.) is a type 1 bare-metal hypervisor: you can't install it on top of another operating system.  You might have some luck with VirtualBox, depending on what you want to do, as it's a type 2 hypervisor and runs on top of a host operating system.

You may also have luck using something like chroot or BSD Jails (depending on what OS you're running; you didn't say) to give your users shell access and isolation.

Not to sound offensive, but given your (likely) lack of knowledge in this space, I would strongly recommend NOT going down this road.  It's one thing to charge for hosting a few websites that require perhaps FTP access, but when you're getting into VPS, your customers are going to expect a certain level of quality of service (perhaps even an Service Level Agreement) and you may be biting off more than you can chew.